# ¿Como puedo suavizar y eliminar ruido y oscilaciones en curvas de crecimiento de levaduras?

Tags: python

Tengo unos datos en los que la primera columna se corresponde con el tiempo y el resto de columnas con el crecimiento de diferentes tipos de levaduras para cada muestra, es decir, la columnas serían: Time, Sample 1, Sample 2... Quiero suavizar y eliminar oscilaciones en las curvas que salen de estos datos para que tengan la forma sigmoidea que tienen estas curvas y así luego poder ajustarlo a un modelo mtemático para sacar sus parámetros. He probado con distintas técnicas, una de ellas la transformada walvet, pero me suaviza para todas las muestras con el mismo valor. Me gustaría también si me podéis ayudar en que otras técnicas podría utilizar. Adjunto parte de código que he intentado:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pywt


Time = np.array(transposed_data['Time [h]'])
Growth = np.array(transposed_data['Sample X7'])

# Obtener los coeficientes de la descomposición wavelet
wavelet = 'db4'  # Tipo de wavelet utilizado
level = 3  # Número de niveles de descomposición
coeffs = pywt.wavedec(df['Growth'], wavelet, level=level)

# Filtrar los coeficientes de alta frecuencia
threshold = np.std(coeffs[-1]) * 2  # Umbral de filtrado (ajusta este valor según tus datos)
coeffs_filt = [pywt.threshold(c, value=threshold, mode='soft') for c in coeffs]

# Reconstruir la señal filtrada
reconstructed_signal = pywt.waverec(coeffs_filt, wavelet)

# Crear un nuevo DataFrame con la señal suavizada
df_smoothed = pd.DataFrame({'Time': df['Time'], 'Smoothed': reconstructed_signal})

# Imprimir el DataFrame resultante
print(df_smoothed)

# Visualización de datos originales y suavizados
plt.plot(Time, Growth, label='Datos originales')
plt.plot(Time, reconstructed_signal, label='Señal reconstruida')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo')
plt.ylabel('Crecimiento')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la cual la transformada de Walvet está suavizando todas las muestras con el mismo valor es porque se está aplicando el mismo filtrado a todos los coeficientes. De esta manera, todos los valores serán suavizados de la misma manera para todas las muestras.

Para evitar esto, es necesario aplicar un filtrado separado para cada muestra. De esta forma, se garantiza que el filtrado y la reconstrucción se realicen de forma individual para cada muestra.

Recomiendo el uso del filtro de Savitzky-Golay, que suavizará las curvas de crecimiento de las muestras

[**package scipy**](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/)

```
pip install scipy
```

import

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
```

Primero, crea un nuevo DataFrame para almacenar todos los datos suavizados.

```
df_sm = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Time})
```

Con un loop, recorre todas las columnas de crecimiento de las muestras.

```
for col in transposed_data.columns[1:]:
```

Utilice el filtro para suavizar.

```
smoothed_signal = savgol_filter(transposed_data[col], window_length=5, polyorder=2)
```

Ahora he incluido los datos suavizados en el DataFrame.

```
 df_sm[col] = smoothed_signal
```

results

```
print(df_sm)
```

Después de mostrar todos los datos suavizados.

```
for col in transposed_data.columns[1:]:
    plt.plot(Time, transposed_data[col], label=f'Dados originais - {col}')
    plt.plot(Time, df_sm[col], label=f'Suavizado - {col}')
```

código completo

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

Time = np.array(transposed_data['Time [h]'])
Growth = np.array(transposed_data['Sample X7'])

 
df_sm = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Time})

 
for col in transposed_data.columns[1:]:
    smoothed_signal = savgol_filter(transposed_data[col], window_length=5, polyorder=2)
    df_sm[col] = smoothed_signal
print(df_sm)

 
for col in transposed_data.columns[1:]:
    plt.plot(Time, transposed_data[col], label=f'Dados originais - {col}')
    plt.plot(Time, df_sm[col], label=f'Suavizado - {col}')

plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.ylabel('Crescimento')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Entiendo la preocupación de la comunidad por no permitir el uso de inteligencia artificial y respeto las reglas, soy programador desde hace 20 años y conozco bien los lenguajes de programación.